# How to display Kannada (Indic) Fonts in a Java application

Tags: java, fonts, indic

I am trying to dislplay a kannda character in a Java app.

`String fonts[] = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();`

This shows that there is a font family by name "BRH Kannada"

`Font f = new Font("BRH Kannada", Font.PLAIN, 20);`

and then I do

`button.setFont(f);`

now when i set the button text, I have to ideally get the text on button to use the BRH kannada font.

However, what and how should I give the string as?

Comment: Are you using Swing or JavaFx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that you are trying to create a Java string literal containing kannada characters:

- If you have a text editor / IDE and Java compiler that is capable of handling UTF-8 files, you can simply put kannada characters into the string:

  String buttonText = "ಅಈಧ";
- If you want your source files to be editable / compilable with a tool chain that is not UTF-8 capable, you can express the kannada characters as Unicode escapes; i.e. \uxxxx where xxxx are 4 hex digits.

  String buttonText = "\u0c85\u0c88\u0ca7";

Answer (score 0):

1.just convert your kannada text(it will be in ascii) to unicode. 
[here is the link to convert http://aravindavk.in/ascii2unicode/]

2.copy the unicode text in java file.

```js
String[] v={"ತಾಯಿ","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p"};
```

3. save the file in utf-8
   then run it will work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpLNG.png)